# MATLAB; Lagrange Polynomial, an Interesting Error

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, numerical, polynomial-math

In my school homework I was given a problem, that required me to calculate Lagrange polynomial. The data set (x,y) involved x = 0,1,2....20,
while y = x - 0.3*rand() + 1;
Then we were asked to observed [Runge's Phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).
After that, we were asked to compute [Chebyshev Nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes) around the edge to remove this phenomenon. Well, this is where I somehow got stuck. The Lagrange polynomial I'm calculating, at this moment, is not going through every data point.

The lagrange polynomial function I used is,

```
function P = lagrangepoly(x, y)
   %checks if two inputs vectors are obtained
   if nargin ~= 2
      error('The function accepts only two arguments of equal length'); 
   end
   
   sz = size(x); %size of x
   sz2 = size(y); % size of y
   
   %checks if size of x and size of y matches and they are row vectors
   if (sz(1) ~= sz2(1)) || (sz(2) ~= sz2(2)) || (sz(1) ~= 1)
       error('Mismatch in length or unsupported arguments.');
   end
   
   %takes the length of thevectors
   len = sz(2);
   
   %creating a emplt 1xlen container
   P = zeros(1, len);
   for i=1:1:len
       %poly evaluates all the convolution of [1 -x(j)] except at x(i)
       %prod evaluates all the product of (x(i) - x(j)) except at x(i)
       P = P + (poly(x((1:len)~=i)) ./ prod(x(i)-x((1:len)~=i))) .* y(i);
   end
end
```

And the dataset I'm using for this, is:
xn = [0    0.5000    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000    7.0000    8.0000    9.0000   10.0000   11.0000   12.0000   13.0000   14.0000   15.0000   16.0000   17.0000   18.0000   19.0000   19.5000   20.0000];

yn =[0.7363    1.4701    1.7802    2.8232    3.9698    4.9934    5.9747    6.8635    7.9435    8.9775    9.9013   10.9318   11.8988   12.8343   13.7095   14.9318   15.8800   16.7028   17.8614   18.7046   19.8505   20.2849   20.7036];

The curve I'm getting can be seen [image: here]

The blue curve gives the original dataset, and the green curve gives the points evaluated from the polynomial.
Can anyone give me suggestion on how do I remove this error. I think this is some kind of precision error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations! You are the 10 millionth (and 3) person to have run into this problem. :)

It is precision. A Lagrange polynomial through 21 points will be a 20'th degree polynomial.

So you are raising numbers on the order of 20 to the 20th power. Then you are adding and subtracting them from other numbers that may be on the order of 1. (However you evaluate that polynomial, it will cause these same issues.)

What is the range of numbers that a double can handle? About 16 decimal digits. Expect to see numerical garbage. No surprise, you did.

How do you avoid it? Don't use high order polynomials! (By the way, the reason you were given this example is to see exactly that result. Every first class in numerical methods has such an example in it.)